# How to skip over a environment variable when iterating over them

Tags: python

this is my code:

```py
import os

def main():
  g = input("What's the password?\n")
  if g == os.environ['master-password']:
    for name, value in os.environ.items():
      if name == "master-password":
        break #obviously just ends the program
      else:  
        print("{0}: {1}".format(name, value))
      
main()
```

I want to skip the master password so it is not revealed.
The reason I want this is that I'm using replit

Comment: Break exists the loop, not ends the program. It just so happens that your program does nothing after the loop.

Comment: Anybody running the script can already see the environment it receives. If they want to see the master password, they can.

Comment: @chepner This looks like a toy program, so that's probably not the point here. Besides, who knows, OP could be running this in a container they control with stdin/stdout hooked up to a TTY or whatnot.

Comment: Still, if user can read it from `os.environ` that means it's not a secret value.

Comment: @matszwecja That's... beside the point. The user could just as well modify this script to not have the check.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm agreeing with @chepner that this check adds 0 additional security, to a value that does not require any safety from the code's POV in the first place. As far as learning purposes go, it does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) instead of [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) to skip to the next iteration of the loop.

```
g = input("What's the password?\n")
if g == os.environ["master-password"]:
    for name, value in os.environ.items():
        if name == "master-password":
            continue
        print(f"{name}: {value}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) with [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement).

```
g = input("What's the password?\n")
if g == os.environ["master-password"]:
    for name, value in os.environ.items():
        if name == "master-password":
            pass
        else:
            print(f"{name}: {value}")
```